# Change onDraw Bitmap when touching the display

Tags: android, bitmap, touch-event, ondraw

I have a question to my code. I want my bitmap to change everytime someone touches the display.

```
protected boolean processTouch(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

        player.setGraphic(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Game.res, R.drawable.sprite2));

    } 
    return true;
}
```

In my player.java file I put:

```
public class Player extends Sprite
{
public Player(int x, int y)
{
    super(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Game.res, R.drawable.sprite1), x-350, y, 50, 17, 5, 2);

}
public void update()
{
getGraphic();
}

public Bitmap getGraphic() 
{
    return bitmap;
}
public void setGraphic(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    this.bitmap = bitmap;
}


private Bitmap bitmap;}
```

My Sprite class contains:

```
 public Sprite(Bitmap bitmap, int x, int y, int width, int height, int fps, int frameCount) 
{
    this.bitmap = bitmap;

}
public Bitmap getGraphic() 
{
    return bitmap;
}
private Bitmap bitmap;
```

And then I want to display it:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(s.getGraphic(), s.getSourceRect(), destRect, null);
```

However when I try to start the game it crashes. How can I solve this problem?

**EDIT**:

the log:

```
02-15 15:29:51.174: I/ActivityManager(18563): Displayed com.example.nic_beta/.Game: +488ms
02-15 15:29:51.197: W/dalvikvm(29635): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x419cb930)
02-15 15:29:51.197: E/AndroidRuntime(29635): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-23004
02-15 15:29:51.197: E/AndroidRuntime(29635): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-15 15:29:51.197: E/AndroidRuntime(29635):    at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfRecycled(Canvas.java:1025)
02-15 15:29:51.197: E/AndroidRuntime(29635):    at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1127)
02-15 15:29:51.197: E/AndroidRuntime(29635):    at com.example.nic_beta.Panel.onDraw(Panel.java:70)
02-15 15:29:51.197: E/AndroidRuntime(29635):    at com.example.nic_beta.RunnerThread.run(Panel.java:187)
02-15 15:29:51.213: W/ActivityManager(18563):   Force finishing activity com.example.nic_beta/.Game
02-15 15:29:51.260: W/ActivityManager(18563):   Force finishing activity com.example.nic_beta/.Menu
```

Comment: If you have a crash, post the logcat.  Also, decoding the bitmap on every touch down woul be very expensive, it would be better to decode once at the beginning and set it to the pre-decoded bitmap on touch.

Answer (score 0):

For the throwIfRecycled error, [this is a possible solution](http://www.nowherenearithaca.com/2011/06/solved-bizarre-null-pointer-thrown-in.html).

But, like Gabe said, you should decode your Bitmap once when your app is created and then draw it when you want it.